# How to send Firebase push notifications to React Native mobile app from Node.js server

Tags: node.js, firebase, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging, nestjs

I have a Node.js + Nest.js server that pushes notifications to all devices that have push-token. I am using Firebase Cloud Messaging service (FCM). The method looks like this:

```
async notifyAll(message: INotification) {
    const documentsAll = await this.repository.find({
      query: {},
      skip: 0,
      limit: 0,
      sort: undefined,
    });

    const tokens = documentsAll.map((item) => {
      if (item.token) return item.token;
    });
    const chunks = _.chunk(tokens, 100);
    try {
      for (const chunk of chunks) {
        await this.admin.messaging().sendMulticast({notification: message, tokens: chunk});
        return 'Notification sent successfully';
      }
    } catch (error) {
      return `Error sending notification:, ${error}`;
    }
```

This code works fine with browsers like Chrome, Firefox etc, however my colleague who is building React native mobile app not receiving push notifs even if he generated push-tokens.

My questions are more theoretical:

1. Should this code work fine with React native apps or maybe I need to tweak it a bit to make it work?
2. Should I create a new mobile project in Firebase to connect my server with his app?

I've googled this, but was not able to find a proper answer